# Inline javascript is not processed in Thymeleaf template when rendered as html-text

Tags: spring-boot, google-visualization, thymeleaf

I have a small SpringBoot application that builds a report and I want to sent this report via email. To build a  report I use Thymeleaf. To build charts I use google-charts which I render and insert as images.

The template I use to show the report on the page and to render the content of the email are the same:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Report Generator</title>
    <script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}"/>
</head>
<body class="d-flex h-100 text-center">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="p-4 p-md-5 mb-4">
        <h1>Report Generator</h1>
        <div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-sm text-center" style="font-size:1.7rem">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Test plan</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Pass</th>
                        <th>Failed</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr th:each="data: ${allData}">
                        <td><a th:href="@{'https://jira.com/browse/' + ${data.testPlanId}}"
                               th:text="${data.testPlanId}"/></td>
                        <td th:text="${data.testExecutions[0].summary}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${data.testExecutions[0].testCaseResults.get('PASS')}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${data.testExecutions[0].testCaseResults.get('FAIL')} + ${allData[0].testExecutions[0].testCaseResults.get('NEW')}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12" th:each="data,stat:${allData}">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 th:text="${data.testExecutions[0].summary} +' ('+${data.testPlanId}+')'"/>
                <div th:id="'chart_div'+${stat.index}" class="w-100 mw-100 p-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script th:inline="javascript">
        var testExecutionData = /*[[${testExecutionData}]]*/'noValue';
        var allData = /*[[${allData}]]*/'noValue';

        $(document).ready(function() {
            google.charts.load('current', {
                packages : [ 'corechart', 'bar' ]
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawColumnChart);
        });


        function drawColumnChart() {
            for (i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
                var data = prepareData(allData[i].testExecutions);

                var options = {
                   colors: ['#06a10f', '#cc0808', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'],
                   annotations: {
                    alwaysOutside: true,
                      textStyle: {
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: '#000',
                        auraColor: 'none'
                      }
                    }
                };
                var chartObj = document.getElementById('chart_div'+i);
                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartObj);

                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
                    chartObj.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
                  });
                chart.draw(data, options);

            }
        }

        function prepareData(data){
            var chartData =  new google.visualization.DataTable();
            chartData.addColumn('string', 'Test Execution');
            chartData.addColumn('number', 'Passed');
            chartData.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
            chartData.addColumn('number', 'Failed');
            chartData.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
            chartData.addColumn('number', 'New');
            chartData.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
            var size = (data.length < 5) ? data.length : 5;
            for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
                chartData.addRow([testExecutionData[i].key,
                data[i].testCaseResults.PASS,
                data[i].testCaseResults.PASS.toString(),
                data[i].testCaseResults.FAIL,
                data[i].testCaseResults.FAIL.toString(),
                data[i].testCaseResults.NEW,
                data[i].testCaseResults.NEW.toString()
                ]);
            }
            return chartData;
        }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The report successfully rendered and shown on the page as expected, but inline-js is not triggered when I render the email (not images of the charts inserted). I process the template for email like this:

```
public void sendMessageUsingThymeleafTemplate(
        String to, String subject, Map<String, Object> templateModel)
        throws MessagingException {

    Context thymeleafContext = new Context();
    thymeleafContext.setVariables(templateModel);
    String htmlBody = thymeleafTemplateEngine.process("report.html", thymeleafContext);
    sendHtmlMessage(to, subject, htmlBody);
}
```

Why Thymeleaf behaves differently regarding inline script when renders the page and when render it to html-text?

Comment: the charts are drawn asynchronously, which is why you need to wait for the `'ready'` event before inserting the image. you would also need to wait on the `'ready'` event before sending the email...

Comment: @WhiteHat thank you for the hint. Do you mean smith like document.readystate===‘complete’?

Comment: no, it's in your code above --> `google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {`

Comment: But for the email it uses the same template thus it waits for ready state when generating email...or I miss something?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can run javascript in emails... even if everything is correct when you send it.

Comment: @Metroids I think it is nothing to do with emails since I checked the body of the generated html before I sent: String htmlBody = thymeleafTemplateEngine.process("report.html", thymeleafContext); There is some difference when View is rendered when I open page in browser and when i process it “manually”

Answer (score 0):

I opened the html that thymeleafTemplateEngine rendered for me in a browser and it shown all the charts. Apparently it is browser's job to process the javascript not Thymeleaf. I need to find a way to preprocess the email before sending it to get all those images inserted like I am getting in the browser

```
<div id="chart_div0" class="w-100 mw-100 p-3"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBvx...">
```